# Shopify trying to add all products to homepage

Tags: shopify, product

I am trying to add all my products to the front page and not only a selection of 3, i'm a major newby with shopify if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

```
{% for product in collections.frontpage.products %}
{% include 'product' with product %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}
    {% include 'product' with product %}
{% endfor %}
```

Although it's probably better to alter your `frontpage` collection to include all products. Use a smart collection with the condition [Product price is greater than 0](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/collections/taking-control-of-your-catalog-page#how-do-i-reorder-products).

If you have more than 50 products you'll need to use [pagination](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/add-view-all-to-collection-pages).

Here's a similar question: [How do I display all of my products on my home page using Shopify and Liquid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008035/1367622).